# Django: Haystack resets, won't find results, when syncing with Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, django-haystack

I just uploaded my first Django project to Heroku and, thus far, it's working will with one exception.

Every time I push an updated version of the project to Heroku...

```
git push heroku master
```

...Haystack no longer recognizes any of the items in the database, resulting in empty search results. This isn't even a migration; just a regular push of any updated code. When new items are added, these appear in a search. But when another sync takes place, the results turn up empty. I'm using Haystack with Woosh.

I'm not sure how to rectify this or what may be causing this. If anyone has any experience or knowledge that may help, it would be welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean: "no longer recognizes any of the items in the database"? Does this mean the old search results are still there but the link when you click on them is incorrect? Or is the search index empty with no search results at all times?

Comment: The latter is indeed the problem. After syncing, no search results appear.

Comment: Does the push delete the Whoosh search index file? Because it sounds like that is happening.

Comment: Perhaps. Is there a way to check for that?

Comment: Your settings file has the location of the search index. Check if a search index file gets deleted there when you push.

Comment: It looks like there are several new search indexes that have been created.

Comment: Well, if the push deletes the search index file then you need to perform a `rebuild_index` or `update_index` command to recreate the search index. That's all there is to it basically. Or you can prevent the search index file from getting deleted by putting it in a different location (if that is even possible, I'm not familiar with Heroku).

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. I don't think the problem is in deleting the index files, because even after rebuilding the index. I still do get empty list of results returned.